# Reassigning a value to a character array not working

Tags: c#, arrays

I am currently having issues reassigning a value to a character array.  Below is my code (unfinished solution to find the next smallest palindrome):

```
public int nextSmallestPalindrome(int number)
    {
        string numberString = number.ToString();

        // Case 1: Palindrome is all 9s
        for (int i = 0; i < numberString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numberString[i] != '9')
            {
                break;
            }
            int result = number + 2;
            return result;
        }

        // Case 2: Is a palindrome
        int high = numberString.Length - 1;
        int low = 0;
        bool isPalindrome = true;
        for (low = 0; low <= high; low++, high--)
        {
            if (numberString[low] != numberString[high])
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        char[] array = numberString.ToCharArray();
        if (isPalindrome == true)
        {
            // While the middle character is 9
            while (numberString[high] == '9' || numberString[low] == '9')
            {
                array[high] = '0';
                array[low] = '0';
                high++;
                low--;
            }
            int replacedvalue1 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(numberString[high]) + 1;
            int replacedvalue2 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(numberString[low]) + 1;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(new string(array));
            if (high == low)
            {
                result[high] = (char)replacedvalue1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                result[high] = (char)replacedvalue1;
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                result[low] = (char)replacedvalue2;
            }


            return Int32.Parse(result.ToString());
        }
        else return -1;

    }
```

Main class runs:

```
Console.WriteLine(nextSmallestPalindrome(1001));
```

This returns 1001, then 101 and then gives a formatexception at the return Int32.Parse(result.ToString()); statement.

I am very confused, as I believe "result" should be 1101 after I assign result[high] = (char)replacedvalue1;. Printing replacedvalue1 gives me "1" as expected. However, debugging it line by line shows that "1001" turns into "1  1" at the end, signifying strange characters.

What could be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This is best solved using a debugger. Please debug it.

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm. Can you describe it? What is high, low? Why do you replace something at all? What output do you expect? Show some examples.

Comment: So far, my algorithm checks the first case, if a string is all 9s; in which case, the next highest palindrome is 1x1, where x = the corresponding number of 0s. The second case is if the string is already a palindrome; to find the next highest palindrome number, I make high and low the index of the first numbers that are NOT 9s; an example of this would be 191, or 1991. I change all the 9s to 0s, and I want to add 1 to the next number at the high and low index. For example, this would change 191 to 202, or 1991 to 2002. In the case of my test, 1001 should change to 1111, where indexes: 1 and 2.

Comment: Typo in the above description, I am always trying to find the next smallest palindrome number, not the next highest. For example, the next smallest palindrome after 101 is 111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characters and numbers aren't the same thing.  I find it easiest to keep an [ASCII chart](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ascii%20chart) open when doing this sort of thing.
If you look at one of those charts, you'll see that the *character* 0 actually has a decimal value of 48.

```
char c = (char)48; // Equals the character '0'
```

The reverse is also true:

```
char c = '0';
int i = (int)c; // Equals the number 48
```

You managed to keep `char`s and `int`s separate for the most part, but at the end you got them mixed up:

```
// Char.GetNumericValue('0') will return the number 0
// so now replacedvalue1 will equal 1
int replacedvalue1 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(numberString[high]) + 1;
// You are casting the number 1 to a character, which according to the
// ASCII chart is the (unprintable) character SOH (start of heading)
result[high] = (char)replacedvalue1;
```

FYI you don't actually need to cast a char back-and-forth in order to perform operations on it.  `char c = 'a'; c++;` is valid, and will equal the next character on the table ('b').  Similarly you can increment numeric characters:
`char c = '0'; c++; // c now equals '1'`

*Edit:* The easiest way to turn an integer 1 into the character '1' is to "add" the integer to the character '0':

```
result[high] = (char)('0' + replacedvalue1);
```

Of course there are much easier ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, but these techniques (converting and adding `char`s and `int`s) are good tools to know.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that; this makes complete sense. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to show you how to convert an integer to a character.  If this answer helped you, up-vote it.  If it solved your problem, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: One more thing, be careful with your ranges.  If you read the number 9, add 1 you have 10.  Add 10 to '0' and you get the character ':' which will also fail to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have write that much code to do it.

Here is your IsPalindrome method;

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int n)
{
    string ns = n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var reversed = string.Join("", ns.Reverse());
    return (ns == reversed);
}

private static int FindTheNextSmallestPalindrome(int x)
{
   for (int i = x; i < 2147483647; i++)
   {
       if (IsPalindrome(i))
       {
           return i;
       }
   }
   throw new Exception("Number must be less than 2147483647");
}
```

This is how you call it. You do not need an array to call it. You can just enter any number which is less than 2147483647(max value of int) and get the next palindrome value.

```
  var mynumbers = new[] {10, 101, 120, 110, 1001};
  foreach (var mynumber in mynumbers)
  {
       Console.WriteLine(FindTheNextPalindrome(mynumber));
  }
```

Comment: This is probably a nice solution for a different problem, but the OP's method has this signature: `int nextSmallestPalindrome(int number)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: So did you mean to say that OP is trying to call a method without knowing what numbers are to be used?

Comment: No, the signature to his code is different from yours. Your code doesn't do what the OP's code is trying to do. You didn't answer his question and you put up code which is similar, but doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: @Enigmativity. Ok I take it as a positive comment. Answer altered.